# How to write a script to move files with a specific name from folder "A" to folder "B" in my Google drive?

Tags: filenames, cp, file-copy, file-transfer, google-drive

How can I write a script that moves files **with a certain name** from a certain folder **to another certain folder** in my Google drive?

Example: I have a folder named 'A' with three files named 'X', 'Y', and 'Z'. I want to move the file 'X' out of that folder to another folder 'B', and the file 'Y' to another folder 'C'.

This is maybe a bit messy, but I basically want to move files with certain names to a certain folder on my Google Drive.

I would be very grateful if someone made a full script that I just can copy and paste.

Comment: How do you access your "google drive"?

Comment: Do you use Nautilus to access the Google drive, or an app such as those named here: https://itsfoss.com/use-google-drive-linux/  ?

Comment: I found it easy to use https://script.google.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have a directory like this :

```
.
├── X.1
├── X.2
├── X.3
├── Y.1
├── Y.2
└── Z.1
```

then

```
mkdir A
mv *X* A
```

(`*X*` means every file or folder containing X in its name)

results in

```
.
├── A
│   ├── X.1
│   ├── X.2
│   └── X.3
├── Y.1
├── Y.2
└── Z.1
```